# How to mock $window.location.href in Angular using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have a Factory in Angular which contains a function that expects a string as an argument, checks if that string is set as an Get Parameter in the URL and returns the Value of that Parameter if set.

A really simplified version of that function in some sort of pseudo code looks like this

```js
function getParameterValueByName(parameterName) {
  
  url = $window.location.href;
  
  if (parameterName is in url) {
    
    return THE VALUE FROM parameterName;
    
  }
  
}
```

In Jasmine I need to test what this functions returns for different URL's. I have to run multiple Tests with different values in `$window.location.href`. But how to mock `$window.location.href`?

+++++

I finally found a way to do it. I just had to add this snippet. And everytime I want to change this URL I just create a new describe Block.

```js
beforeEach(module('myApp', function ($provide) {
      $provide.value('$window', {location: {href: 'https://www.example.com?foo=bar&foo2=bar2'}});
}));
```

Comment: Create an object `$window` and add `location` property then the `href` property to `location`. Your code is only getting one value so you just need to make sure it exists. Then you can set the value to whatever you need to test your function.

Comment: I dont know if I understood this right, but if I just create an object like you suggested, inside the Function Jasmine will still use the localhost URL on which Karma is running.

Answer (score 1):

There are heaps of ways to achieve this, but I'd say the best way would be to make a small factory for window itself :

```
function getParameterValueByName(parameterName) {

  url = getWindow().location.href

  if (parameterName is in url) {

    return THE VALUE FROM parameterName;

  }

function getWindow(){
 return $window.location.href;

}
```

And when mocking it :

```
function getWindow(){ // in your test
 return {
     location:{
       href:"What ever mock href u want"
     }
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you be more precise? Where do I have to add this mock? Also I think `url = getWindow().location.href`should be `url = getWindow();` ?